# Convert soap response to json

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot, soap

I have the below soap response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:confirmPayer_10Response xmlns:ns2="http://v1.ws.provider.acp.com/">
         <return>
            <KeyValues>
               <Key>MICROFILM_NUMBER</Key>
               <Data>71111112236100141977490</Data>
            </KeyValues>
            <KeyValues>
               <Key>USER_TOKEN</Key>
               <Data>hpuser</Data>
            </KeyValues>
            <KeyValues>
               <Key>PASSWORD_TOKEN</Key>
               <Data>hpuser+22**</Data>
            </KeyValues>
         </return>
      </ns2:confirmPayer_10Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i convert this response to json like below

```
{
   "MICROFILM_NUMBER" : "71111112236100141977490",
   "USER_TOKEN" : "hpuser",
   "PASSWORD_TOKEN" : "hpuser+22**"
}
```

Comment: 1. Get the XML answer from the SOAP body. 2. Loop through the KeyValues. 3. For each key-value, store it into a Map 4. Serialize the Map to Json and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) can convert xml to json.

```
        String xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            "   <soap:Body>\n" +
            "      <ns2:confirmPayer_10Response xmlns:ns2=\"http://v1.ws.provider.acp.com/\">\n" +
            "         <return>\n" +
            "            <KeyValues>\n" +
            "               <Key>MICROFILM_NUMBER</Key>\n" +
            "               <Data>71111112236100141977490</Data>\n" +
            "            </KeyValues>\n" +
            "            <KeyValues>\n" +
            "               <Key>USER_TOKEN</Key>\n" +
            "               <Data>hpuser</Data>\n" +
            "            </KeyValues>\n" +
            "            <KeyValues>\n" +
            "               <Key>PASSWORD_TOKEN</Key>\n" +
            "               <Data>hpuser+22**</Data>\n" +
            "            </KeyValues>\n" +
            "         </return>\n" +
            "      </ns2:confirmPayer_10Response>\n" +
            "   </soap:Body>\n" +
            "</soap:Envelope>";
        U.Builder builder = U.objectBuilder().fromXml(xml);
        U.Builder out = U.objectBuilder();
        out.add(builder.get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.0.Key"),
            builder.<Object>get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.0.Data"));
        out.add(builder.get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.1.Key"),
            builder.<Object>get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.1.Data"));
        out.add(builder.get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.2.Key"),
            builder.<Object>get("soap:Envelope.soap:Body.ns2:confirmPayer_10Response.return.KeyValues.2.Data"));
        System.out.println(out.toJson());
```

```json
{
  "MICROFILM_NUMBER": "71111112236100141977490",
  "USER_TOKEN": "hpuser",
  "PASSWORD_TOKEN": "hpuser+22**"
}
```